# What is the privilege required to create unique/primary key constraint in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle12c, privileges

Though it feels like asking a very basic question without much research, posting this question here after much searching in Oracle forums, AskTom, Oracle Docs & SOF. I am trying to narrow down the privilege required to create unique key constraint or primary key constraint. This is because trying to create a simple table with unique/primary key fails with insufficient privileges.

```
SQL> connect sys/syspass
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> grant create session, create table, create any index, 
     create indextype, unlimited tablespace to tuser1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> 
SQL> connect tuser1/tuserp1
Connected.
SQL> create table tab1 (
atomic          int unique,
symbol          varchar2(2) unique,
name            char(15)
);  2    3    4    5  
create table tab1 (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> create table tab2 (empno number, name varchar2(30), sal number,
constraint pk_tab2 primary key (empno));  2  
create table tab2(empno number, name varchar2(30), sal number,
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL>
```

Can please help me with finding the possible missing permission in this case?

Comment: You may find a better audience for this question @ dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you able to create the table without ANY constraints? Try and post the answer here - it will help either way.

Comment: @mathguy Yes i am able to create table

Answer (score 2):

granting `resource` must resolve the issue :

```
SQL> conn tuser1/tuserp1
Connected.
SQL> create table tab2 (empno number, name varchar2(30), sal number,
constraint pk_tab2 primary key (empno));    
create table tab2 (empno number, name varchar2(30), sal number,
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant resource to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn tuser1/tuserp1
Connected.
SQL> create table tab2 (empno number, name varchar2(30), sal number,
constraint pk_tab2 primary key (empno));    

Table created.
```

Comment: Yes, with resource also it hits into the same issue.

Comment: @learningloop i've tested in my medium without issue. ( When i `revoke resource from myschema` ) create table DDL says `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` also.

Comment: Thank you for verifying your solution. Finally narrowed down the cause of the issue. The dba had set [lockdown](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-pdb-lockdown-profiles-12cr2) profiles on the database, by disallowing constraints which are other than `rely` constraints. Also, found that the privileges required for `unique` and `primary` keys are [`unlimited tablespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/indexes.htm#ADMIN-GUID-BF04684D-A857-4046-8749-0F57D3B19113). My apologies for creating a confusion. Thought of deleting this question, but wanted to convey the finding.

Comment: @learningloop Thank you, too. No need to delete i think, for the sake of `resource` :)

Comment: The use of the `resource` role is discouraged since Oracle 11

Comment: The same goes for `connect`, I'd say.

Comment: @learningloop: Can you write this as an answer, please? I'm new to 12c and haven't heard about lockdown profiles, so thanks for finding that!